# How can I find in google pages with "<<<XML" in google?

Tags: search

How can I google pages with strictly `<<<XML` text?

I'v tried `"<<<XML"` but i receive pages with XML text without less signs...

Also I don't know what stackExchange community should I post my question, correct me please if I should use another.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can trick the search engine by replacing the `<` character with its xml-entity equivalent `&lt;` : `"&lt;&lt;&lt;XML"` (see this [search link](https://www.google.com/search?q="%26lt%3B%26lt%3B%26lt%3BXML")).

Not sure if all the results are shown, but some are. ;)

Comment: can you give me search link? Pasting to google search field doesn't work for me...

Comment: you searched &lt it found &lt ) it doesnt't search < i think.

Comment: Not really, in HTML `<` is escaped in `&lt;`. Google found both `&lt;` and escaped `<`. In the results, I have, for example :
https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/phpxml-domdocument-33342
and
http://cgi.geocities.jp/php_manual_info/index.php?file=book.simplexml.html
which actually contains `<<<XML`